# Update Next Row If Current Updated Row 0

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a table looks like this :

```
HarvestID  |  CheckIn | Actual | Status
1          |   Date   | 100    | Process
2          |   Date   | 200    | Process
3          |   Date   | 400    | Process
```

and my problem is how to update next row if I set the Qty='350' Then Update ID '1' & '2' to 0, and ID '3' Qty='350'

is there a way to do this without make a new table to stock the Total of 'A' Qty's and using stored procedure ?

What already I try is :

```
    cmdTemp = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_harvest ORDER BY CheckIn ASC LIMIT 1", cn)
    sqlrd = cmdTemp.ExecuteReader
    While sqlrd.Read
        harvestid = sqlrd("HarvestID")
        qtyTemp1 = sqlrd("Actual") - Qty : qtyTemp2 = sqlrd("Actual")
    End While
    sqlrd.Close()
    If qtyTemp1 < 0 Then
        cmdTemp = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE tb_harvest SET Actual=0 WHERE HarvestID=" & harvestid & "; " & _
                                   "UPDATE tb_harvest SET Actual=Actual+" & qtyTemp1 & " WHERE HarvestID=" & harvestid + 1, cn)
        cmdTemp.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        cmdTemp = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE tb_harvest SET Actual=Actual-" & qtyTemp2 & " WHERE HarvestID=" & harvestid, cn)
        cmdTemp.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with variables:

```
set @qty = 350;

update tb_harvest
    set actual = (case when @qty <= 0 then 0
                       when @qty >= actual
                       then if(@qty := @qty - actual, 0, 0)
                       when (@tmp := actual - @qty),
                       then if(@qty := 0, @tmp, @tmp)
                       else actual -- should never happen
                  end)
    order by harvestid;
```

Comment: this code is work great Thanks ! @GordonLinoff
If I try using it in the VB.net it return error to say qty or tmp is not defined, how to resolve that